# how to change an uilabel from another class

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have my ViewController.h/m and another class Keyboard.h/m.
In my ViewController.h I have an UILabel:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

UILabel *label;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

and my ViewController.m looks so

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@synthesize label;
...
```

Now I want to change the label from Keyboard.m. 
I have tried something like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
...
ViewController *vc;
vc.label.text = @"text";
```

it compiles without any errors but the label doesn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very error prone that you're doing here.

```
ViewController *vc;
```

declares a pointer, but this won't be initialized; so when you're accessing its property vc.label.text, objc_messageSend() will be passed a bogus pointer, so it can potentially crash! (you're lucky if id didn't do so.)

Anyways: if you have done it well, like `ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];` creating a new instance wouldn't have affected the other instance. You have to store the pointer to your instance somewhere, e. g. set a `@property (retain) ViewContrller *vc;` to your application's app delegate object, and access it through that property like this:

```
[(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] vc].label.text = @"new text";
```

that way it should work.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

How are you initiating your vc variable? I am guessing that is where the error is coming from. Try doing:

> vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@ ViewController"];

If you are already doing that, make sure your IBOutlet is hooked up correctly. You are setting the variable correctly so the error must be coming from somewhere else.